# How to change the values of a multidimensional array in a range?

Tags: java, loops, for-loop, multidimensional-array

I want to change the values of a 2d array from a given starting position (`rowPos` and `colPos`) for a certain amount of `rows` and `columns`.

So far I have the code below:

```
int[][] block = new int[10][10];

int rowPos = 3, colPos = 3;
int rows = 4, columns = 4;

for (int i = rowPos; i < rows; i++)
    for (int j = colPos; j < columns; j++)
        block[i][j] = 1;

for (int[] x : block) {
    for (int y : x)
        System.out.print(y + " ");
    System.out.println();
}
```

However this gives me the following output:

```
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
```

It is only setting the value at `rowPos` and `colPos`. This is my expected output:

```
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
0 0 0 1 1 1 1 0 0 0 
0 0 0 1 1 1 1 0 0 0 
0 0 0 1 1 1 1 0 0 0 
0 0 0 1 1 1 1 0 0 0 
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
```

I feel like I'm close but missing something small, please help me!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change the loops to this:

```
for (int i = rowPos; i < rows + rowPos; i++)
    for (int j = colPos; j < columns + colPos; j++)
        block[i][j] = 1;
```

In your code, you let `i` and `j` start at the row and column you want to begin changing the values. That's fine, but it also means your condition doesn't work anymore. Let me show you what happens:

1. You declare `i` and set it's value to 3.
2. You check if `i` (3) is less than `rows` (4). Success!
3. You declare `j` and set it's value to 3.
4. You check if `j` (3) is less than `columns` (4). Success!
5. You set `block[3][3]` to `1`.
6. `j` is incremented by 1 and is now 4.
7. You check if `j` (4) is less than `columns` (4). Fail!
8. `i` is incremented by 1 and is now 4.
9. You check if `i` (4) is less than `rows` (4). Fail!
10. You print the array's contents.

The problem is that because you start `i` and `j` at values greater than `0`, you need to keep that in mind when performing the check.

Comment: This was so helpful in understanding what I'd actually done wrong. Thank you so much for finding the time to explain this to me in detail!